# python cv2:The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support

Tags: python, opencv

when I run my code , I get this error:"

```
cv2.imshow("Original",I)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I search a lot information,but I still don't know how to solve this problem. Does anyone know how to solve in detail ? My system is Ubuntu ,and python3.5 .
cv2 can be import in python.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, opencv can be installed in the following way

> sudo apt update

> sudo apt install python3-opencv

Confirm installation by

> python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.**version**)"

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like you didn't build your opencv library properly. Could you briefly summarize how you installed-built it? Did you git clone, cmake and make the project from the source code or did you just apt-get install it?

`If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config,`

Make sure you sudo apt-get install these two libraries before you rebuild.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The opencv I build just use pip3 instal .And then it can be import in python .I do not use git clone and cmake... . And I using sudo apt-get install install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config before,but the problem also exist .

Comment: supplementary specification: when I meet that problem ,then I install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config ,and it not work . And when I install them ,it said two of them are both newest .

Comment: Uninstall it, and start from scratch. I always install it this way:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

tldr: 

 - git clone the repo
 - mkdir and cd into `build` folder
 - run cmake with the params from the tutorial
 - pay attention to the cmake log, it will usually point out some missing dependencies like "ffmpeg: unable to find 'pkg-config'"
 - if everything is ok, under 'to be built' modules (also the cmake log) you should see python2 / python3

Comment: here is a problem, I can't uninstall cv2, because I use pip list to check my cv ,but no cv ! But I can import it in python .In my folder python3.5/site-packages/  here is a folder named cv2. should I remove this cv2 folder？And I already have libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config , how to deal with with them?

Comment: I use OpenCV in Java but I would reckon that the case is same for Python: 
Actual code we write is still executed as C++ code, since OpenCV is written in C++. Java uses a native interface to execute code I write in C++, I would say that the same case is for Python. Now for the actual C++ code to be compiled and executed you still need all cpp dependencies, which is why's necessary to install OpenCV from the source code. Just follow the tutorial and the steps above, make sure you pay close attention to cmake output for any missing dependencies, and in the end you should get a library for py.

Comment: It still can't work . I use it in tensorflow . And I use virtualenv to build my tensorflow , and the python that my tensorflow used is python3.5 , it is in my tensorflow .My computer has another python 2,7 and 3.5 . And python 2.7 has no such problem .How can I solve it ?